# How to find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{nx} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{e^{ \frac{x}{n}}} \right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How to find $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{nx} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{e^{x/n}}  \right)$$ 
Ratio, Root test doesn't work. Is there a chance to use comparison test?

Comment: The ratio and root test are tests for convergence of series, but there is no series here.

Comment: but if $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} <1 $ then limit is $0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For large $n$, $1-e^{-x/n}\sim x/n$, so the sought limit is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=0$.